# How to install android 3.2 on an android TV box?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, installation, 3.2-honeycomb

I'm looking for a way to install android 3.2 on an android TV box which is running android 2.3. Is it possible? if possible can someone give me some tips for it please?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Can you please tell us which type of TV box you want to modify? For different hardware there are different constraints.

Comment: Yatay TV box is the brand of it

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are quite a few devices under the "IPTV Box" category listed on Yatay's [site](http://www.eyamay.com/product.asp?sort_id=22).  Knowing the exact model number would help.

Comment: Sorry yeah the model of the particular IPTV Box that i'm talking about is IV303. This [link](http://www.eyamay.com/htmledit/UploadFiles/20111228153646284.pdf) will give you the details of the spec